# Adding a header/TextView above 2 list views

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a Java class and two XML files which are basically just a side by side listView which takes in some values. I want to put a header or a text view above each list view ( they should stay side by side ) however every time I try to add a textView the whole project messes up and following online instructions is not working to implement a header.

```
 public class Leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView UsernameList;
        private ListView ScoreList;

    LocalDatabase localDatabase;

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> list2Adapter;

        //Find the ListView resources
        UsernameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UsernameList);
        ScoreList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ScoreList);

        //Create and populate the list of usernames.
        //This is where the information from the Database would need to be entered. and the String[] removed
        String[] usernames = new String[]{"Andy", "Marie", "George"};
        ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        usernameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(usernames));

        //Create and populate the list of scores
        //This is where the information from the Database would need to be entered. and the Integer[] removed
        Integer[] scores = new Integer[]{7, 4, 1};
        ArrayList<Integer> scoreList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        scoreList.addAll(Arrays.asList(scores));

        //adds the users details to the leaderboard
        localDatabase = new LocalDatabase(this);
        Contact contact = localDatabase.getLoggedInUser();
        //Set a string to have the value of the users name.
        String s = contact.name;
        //Create Array Adapter using the username list
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_row, usernameList);
        //Add more users
        listAdapter.add(s);
        //Set the Array Adapter as the ListView's adapter
        UsernameList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //Create Array Adapter using the username list
        list2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.activity_row, scoreList);
        //Add more users
        list2Adapter.add(0);
        //Set the Array Adapter as the ListView's adapter
        ScoreList.setAdapter(list2Adapter);
    }
}
```

Then the two xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Leaderboard">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/UsernameList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".60"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ScoreList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the two TextViews in a LinearLayout. The linear Layout should span the entire width (match_parent), but only be as high as need be; wrap_content.

What you then want to do to have them neatly divided amongst the width of the screen, is, first off, set the LinearLayout orientation to horizontal. Then, you make the width of and both TextViews 0dp (that's right, 0dp), and their height wrap_content. Then, give both TextViews a weight of 1. The views now both take up half the space (in width) of the LinearLayout. Finally, centre the TextViews for a good looking header.

Ive kept it very broad and non-codey, but I think you should be able to google all the concepts explained above if you run into any trouble. If you really cant figure it out,i'll help you out in the comments.